# How do I suppress warnings with plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

I'd like to stop warnings in plotly without turning off warnings globally

This code is going into a function so it could be run in a different session

This is my code

```
      fit <-
        plot_ly(credit_old, 
            y = ~score, 
            color = ~fte, 
            type = "box")
      suppressWarnings(fit)
```

I still get

```
Warning messages:
1: In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
  minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels

2: In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
  minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels
```

Answer (score 2):

`suppressWarnings(fit)` returns a value which is `fit`. This result then gets auto-printed which is why the warning is shown. It is similar to this

```
result <- suppressWarnings(fit) # No warning here
print(result) # Warning here
#> Warning messages:
#> 1: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
#>   no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#> 2: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
#>   no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

You can call `print` inside `suppressWarnings`. This doesn't result in auto-printing because `print` returns it's value invisibly.

```
suppressWarnings(print(fit))
```